# Any FREE plug-in for VisualStudio that has partial code completion?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

VS2010: one thing Resharper has is that in Intellisence when we are typing the name of a method it shows all suggestions that have the words we are typing somewhere in their name so for example if method name is DoSomethingReallyCool()  and I am not aware of this exact name but I just type "Really" then the its intelliseinse is also showing DoSomethingReallyCool() as a suggestion. this help me A LOT for coding. I was wondering if there is any FREE plug-in with this capability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio 2010 does this now without a plug in.

Take the following excerpt:

```
class Program {
    static void Main( string[] args ) {

    }

    static void ReallyCoolFunction() { };

    static void SuperCoolFunction() { };
}
```

If I type `Cool` inside the main body, both functions show up in the intellisense list.

Comment: nice...I guess I have been such a long time user of Resharper that I do not know what capability is from VS and what is from R#!

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't VS2010 already do this? My copy seems to.
If not then [The Productivity Power tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef) may be what does it on my version. If not then it's still a jolly fine add-in anyway.